# Change icon with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my foray into web development I have found a new problem, I need to change the icon for another one when I click on it. I have an idea of a function in javascript that sends the id of the icon and with the obtain the element, after obtaining element I hope to change keyboard_arrow_up by keyboard_arrow_down. However that is the part that is not performed, how do I get the value keyboard_arrow_up?

```js
function change(iconID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(iconID);
    if (item) {}
}
```

```html
<i id="icon1" onclick="change('icon1')" class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the temporary solution, I had to change the icons of google design material by the fontawesome icons. However, I will continue investigating.

```js
function change (iconID){
  if(document.getElementById(iconID).className=="fa fa-chevron-up"){
    document.getElementById(iconID).className = "fa fa-chevron-down";
  }else{
    document.getElementById(iconID).className = "fa fa-chevron-up";
  }
}
```

```html
<i id="icon1" onclick="change('icon1')" class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like , you need this kind of function

```
function changeIcon(classname or id) {
    $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-circle-arrow-up icon-circle-arrow-down");
}
```

Note : the icons in above solution are copied from internet , please use your desire icons in there.

Comment: jquery wasn't asked for :p

Comment: this is jquery, he needs pure js

Answer (score 0):

Remember Icons are just CSS class, so the function should change the class for another on the javascript function.

```
function change(iconID) {
var element = document.getElementById(iconID);

if (element.classList.contains("keyboard_arrow_up")) {

    element.classList.add("keyboard_arrow_down")

  } else {

    element.classList.add("keyboard_arrow_up")
  }
}
```

Comment: but my class is material-icons if the change would stop working.

Comment: Can't you change a material-icons class with js?? I think it's just a class, try using this way, but if it doesn't work, what js libraries are you using in your project? for this example, change the "keyboard_arrow_down" and the other class for the classes you are going to use. This is like a toggle class with pure js

Answer (score 0):

You can change `innerText` as follows:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    let change = document.querySelector("#icon");

   change.addEventListener('click' ,function () {
       let item = document.querySelector("#icon");

       if(this.innerText == 'keyboard_arrow_down'){
            item.innerText = "keyboard_arrow_up";

        }else{   
            item.innerText = "keyboard_arrow_down";

        }

    })
});
```

and the html:

```
<i id="icon" class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with what PO asked

Comment: @Masoud Keshavarz  You're absolutely right i edit the answer

Comment: PO don't want to change `text`. He wants to change `icon`. If you want to answer the question I give you a hint: you can change `className`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function change(iconID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(iconID);
    if (item) {}
}
```

```html
<i id="icon1" onclick="change('icon1')" class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
```

```html
snap pans
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).